# android studio gui broken

Tags: user-interface, android-studio, java-8, windows-10

I'm having a serious issue with Android Studio.

After using any context menus in the code editor (ex, generate->override methods) or using it for a while the GUI gets broken as shown in the attached screenshot.

Don't know if it's a Java, Android Studio or NVIDIA driver bug.

[image]

System:

- Windows 10 x64 1151 10586.11
- Android Studio: 1.4.1
- Java 1.8 update 66 x64
- Nvidia GTX 970 driver 359.00

UPDATE: I thought it was Java compatibility issue with Windows 10 TH2, so I launched Eclipse to see if the same happened. Nope, it's an Android Studio bug. I have send a bug report to the devs. If someone finds a workaround to fix this, please reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I solved the issue, after searching a lot I found [this page](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration) that explains some of the options we can change in Android Studio. I tried changing some of these options and solved the issue. This is what I did to solved it:

- Created an idea.properties file in Android Studio configuration folder located in C:/Users/"Username"/.AndroidStudio[versionNumber]
- I added this line: "sun.java2d.d3d=false"

Comment: This solution did not resolve it completely but it happens less often now.

Comment: Regardless my previous comment, situation is not workable. Even uninstalled IntelliJ editor but did not help.
Reverted back to Android Studio 1.4. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Any IDE with so many dependencies can easily break down like that (looking at you, Eclipse). It may not be preferable, but I'd try uninstalling it and reinstalling it to see if that helps. It might not identify the issue but you may spend a long time tracking it down if a quick google search doesn't identify the issue.

Comment: I have already reinstalled android studio, the java sdk and the nvidia driver. I've also tried using the java 1.7 sdk. Nothing solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, Windows 10 Pro + Android Studio 1.5 + NVIDIA 980m.

For some reason I didn't even have the idea.properties and studio64.exe.vmoptions files present in the Android Studio profile folder. In any of them (.AndroidStudio, .AndroidStudio1.3, .AndroidStudio1.4, AndroidStudio1.5, AndroidStudio2.0, etc).

What helped me is that I just closed Android Studio, renamed all of these folders (XXX_temp) and then started Android Studio 1.5 again. I allowed it to import the settings from my old .AndroidStudio1.5_temp folder and it created a new .AndroidStudio1.5 folder and now both required files are there. And the UI seems to be fine again, at least for the time being.

I still do not understand with this issue came up at this specific time.